# Analytic solutions for the (large oscillations) simple, variable frequency pendulum.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

It is well known that if we allow for large oscillations the equation for a simple pendulum,

$$
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2\theta(t)}{\mathrm{d}t^2}=-\omega^2\sin\theta(t),
\end{equation*}
$$

can be solved in terms of elliptic integrals. Furthermore, if we allow for a frequency changing with time (not a dynamical variable but an specified function), i.e.,

$$
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}^2\theta(t)}{\mathrm{d}t^2}=-\omega^2(t)\sin\theta(t),
\end{equation*}
$$

I know no solutions reported in the literature even for simple forms of $\omega$ like polynomials. Since the variable $t$ is explicit through $\omega^2(t)$ then the equation is no longer an autonomous equation, and we may a priori say that there is no easy or evident change of variable or substitution that allows for an integration. I would like to know if there are particular cases or methods suited for such an equation.

Comment: Intuition: In cases of very specific choices of $\omega(t)$ there might be an explicit solution, otherwise you are only left with numerical schemes.

Comment: One case is $\omega(t)=1/(at+b)^2$, which can be linearized in the same method as an Euler equation.

Comment: @Eli . Thanks. Do you mean to construct a numeric solution using the Euler method ?

Comment: I misspoke, not linearized but autonomized. For $\omega(t)=1/(at+b)^2$, letting $bx=\ln(at+b)$ transforms it to an autonomous equation.